# Latin translation

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

What would be the correct Latin translation for the text below? It’s for a singular person.

« Remember yesterday, see today and thrive for tomorrow, don’t give up!”.

/ Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Anybody, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong (I'm an active learner of Latin), but I believe that would be:

> "Memento hesternum, vide hunc diem et vige pro crastino, noli desistere!"

This essentially translates into "Remember yesterday, see this day and thrive on behalf of tomorrow, do not give up!"

The verbs are phrased as imperatives (commands) to a singular listener.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Uhh... *memento*? (See https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/memini for example.)

Comment: Also I think you mean *desistere*.

Comment: And *hunc diem* (sorry...)

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel when I chose to include "memine", it was because I was looking for a second person present imperative; however, none was listed. I formed my own present stem through inferences (verb is 3rd conjugation, aka -ere ending, remove -re to get a possible present stem). This is likely bad practice, which is why I chose to include "recall" as an option.

Comment: @gingerwitch64 *Memini* doesn't work like that, but it's also unnecessary, as the ancients used *memento(te)* as the imperative. Think e.g. *memento mori*.

Comment: @cmw thank you for that, that makes sense now. I will update my post.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel two things; first, I have corrected my spelling of "desistere". Second, I used "hoc" as indicated on this page, under etymology: https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/hodie#Latin however forgot that I did indeed need the accusative masculine. I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @gingerwitch64 Oops, I thought I'd catch that last error before I saw your answer. Feel free to save over it in case you were going for something different. One final remark: While pro + acc is found in some Late sources, "on behalf of", in Classical Latin it chiefly takes the ablative.

Comment: @cmw ah, I see; I will update my answer based on that and will assume that Classical Latin is probably what op was looking for. I appreciate the pointers (again, I am an avid learner) and thank you for your help.